# Return values in excel

Tags: excel

I have a data like this:Column a is Machine#, Column B is Data

```
Machine   data
1         1.2
1         1.21
2         1,15
1         1.21
2         1.11
```

I want to get data from machine 1 and put into one column (c) and machine 2 to another column (D).

Please help

Comment: Column A is machine number 1 and 2 and it not a pattern.

Comment: Your description is confusing "get data from machine 1 and put into one column (c) and machine 2 to another column (d)". I have no idea what you want want here. Please update your question with a picture of your desired results or similar data format like you have for your sample data (formatted as code so the line breaks and white space are retained). I have a feeling what you want is a pivot table.

Comment: Why in the column data some numbers have a `.` as decimal separator and others have a `,`?

Comment: vlookup() or index() & match() but hard to guess with the lack of detail...

Answer (score 0):

You can use =IF()

Put in C2: `=IF(A2=1;B2;"")`

And in D2: `=IF(A2=2;B2;"")`

If you select the cells C2 and D2 and click &drag the bottom left corner of D2 down to the rest of the column you get this result:

[image]

Sidenote: Please forgive the ',' in the numbers, and the ';' in the formulas, my Excel has non-standard settings.

Explanation of why this works:
IF() is a simple logic test and it works like this:

IF has 3 elements: IF(A;B;C).

A is your test, this needs to have a true/false result. In this case we check if the value in A2 equals 1. The result determines if it shows B or C.

B is the output if the result of the A=B test is true.

C is the output if the result of the A=B test is false.